# Pass variable from express router to socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, chatroom

I am a new for node/express and was working as PHP developer. I am currently making a chat room website by express and socket io, but I have trouble passing the room id to socket io connection.

Here is my code in server side.

```
var app = require('express');
var router = app.Router();
router.get('/:room_id', function(req, res) {
    var room_id = req.params.room_id;
    var hash = req.query.hash;
    // This function will connect to database and return user information object
    var user_info = getUserInfo(hash);
}
```

How could I pass the variable room_id and user_info to here?

```
io.on('connection', req, res){
    //...code
}
```

Since the user is able to join multiple chatroom with multiple tabs in a browser, I am not sure if session will be the ideal solution. In node, could each tab has independent session?

Comment: use a middleware like `express-session`

Comment: user is able to open multiple rooms with multiple tabs, do there room share the same session, or they could be separate session